# Import YAML in flask

Tags: python, flask, yaml

I have successfully installed the PyYAML:

```
 (venv) D:\myproject>python app.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
 db=yaml.load(open['db.yaml'])
  TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `open['db.yaml']` >>> `open('db.yaml')`

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use PyYAML's `load()`, the documentation says it can be unsafe, and it is very unlikely you cannot use the safe loader. You should also consider if you want to restrict yourself to YAML 1.1 (the 1.2 spec came out in 2009) and deal with the other restrictions of PyYAML.

Answer (score 1):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is a callable builtin, which is not subscriptable (you can't access items via `[]`). What I think you want is to call it, as in:

```
db=yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like the following.

```
import yaml

with open("db.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.load(stream)) # or do something else with it
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```